# wrong output from vertical Tab bootstrap with vue.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have with this script

```
 <vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description">
             <div v-for="(siteParts, index) in sitePartLine">
        <v-tab :title="sitePartLine[index].serial_no" v-if="sitePartLine[index]">

          <div class="description text-left">
                <div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
                  <small v-for="(data, key) in item" :key="key">
                      <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ data }}<br>
                  </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </v-tab>
      </div>
    </vue-tabs>
```

this result:
please see the picture [image]

the problem is when I click on AN000044. I have the same result like when  I click
on BN00000...... all mixed from BN and AN the target ist that result should show it till **access_type**

Comment: Your variable names are very confusing, which doesn't help anyone understanding what you're doing. The problem with your code is that you have to iterate the same object you're using for the "header" on the left also for the iteration of the data fields (on the right). Right now, you're creating the headers on the left and the data on the right from different objects (`sitePartLine` for headers and `siteObject.line_info` for the data).

Comment: @BennettDams ok i change the head :  <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid" v-if="siteObject.line_info[index]"> now i have evrywhere the same and i have still the same result do have idea ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. You should create an object (e.g. called "data" or in your case I guess "lines") in Vue's `data` function which holds all objects you want to display. Then you have one `v-for` to iterate over these object (so all data objects). Inside this `v-for` you create the tab with the title AND create the data fields, where you use the item from the title for the v-for of the data fields.

Comment: @bennett Dams can you show me how am newbies with this if is ok for you thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT for future visitors: The problem with your code is that you have to iterate the same object you're using for the "header" on the left also for the iteration of the data fields (on the right). Right now, you're creating the headers on the left and the data on the right from different objects (`sitePartLine` for headers and `siteObject.line_info` for the data).

After the comments, here's a cleaner version to create the tabs:

```
<template>
    <vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
            <v-tab :title="item.serial_no">
                <div class="description text-left">
                    <!-- the following "item" is from the first v-for -->#
                    <!-- so it's the same object, therefore we don't have duplicates -->
                    <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
                        <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </v-tab>
        </div>
    </vue-tabs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // you have to fill your data object somewhere
    this.data = [
      { lineid: "AN000..", site_id: "123" },
      { lineid: "BN000..", site_id: "456" }
    ];
  }
};
</script>
```